# What's the best way to dim a 5-inch LCD for a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, schematics, lcd, display

I'm trying to make a DPI display to work with my Raspberry Pi. First, I searched around and found out that the 555 timer IC is a good way to control the brightness of the display. Since the background LEDs needs around 23V to function, I've included a step up converter.

But then someone recommended me to use a LED controller instead. Is it a better choice?
And if so, what IC would fit this project? That has both dimming and boosting function.

It's for a LCD like this one: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1680
[image]

Comment: You already asked this today at [This is my first schematic for a LCD using DPI from a Raspberry Pi. But would it better if I just used a LED controller instead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537360/this-is-my-first-schematic-for-a-lcd-using-dpi-from-a-raspberry-pi-but-would-it) please *edit* your existing post if you feel the issues there can be resolved, don't post yet again with only one line changed, especially as this is really now your third posting of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you are using is fine, but it's a much more complicated approach than using an integrated backlight driver IC. The main disadvantages are:

1. The boost converter is regulating the voltage, but the LEDs only care about current, so you'd need to add a current regulator (or at a minimum, a series resistor) to your backlight circuit. This is inefficient and means the default brightness with vary a lot between different screens in a batch.
2. The colour temperature of the LEDs depends on the current, so to get accurate colours, you typically use a combination of current regulation and backlight PWM. A good quality driver IC will allow you to do this but, to be honest, it's probably not a big deal for most applications.
3. The boost converter you're using needs a good voltage ripple filter capacitor which can add a lot of cost. The LEDs don't actually care about quite a bit of ripple so a proper current regulated backlight driver can get away with a smaller inductor and filter capacitor.
4. Driver ICs are almost always inverted topologies, since the LED string doesn't need to be ground referenced. This means they can use an N-channel switching device without needing a fancy driver circuit, which means they will probably have better efficiency than your small switcher at lower cost.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry Pi has two PWM output pins, use on one of them instead of the 555, anb connect it to the bottom resistor of the feedback divider

that gets you software brightness control. which may or may not be preferable to a knob.